# variable names in tidyjson code

Tags: r

I want to write code for the tidyjson package in a function as follows:

```
> enter_object(object) %>%    spread_values(
>     varnames[1] = jstring(strings[1]),
>     varnames[2] = jstring(strings[2]),
>     varnames[3] = jstring(strings[3])   )
```

This code runs fine if i have a literal string like `foo` instead of `varnames[1]`. But I want the function to be more flexible so that I can generate lots of varnames and not write them all by hand.  The variable names end up as names for data frame columns.  With my current failure I get:

```
+         enter_object(object) %>% 
+         spread_values(
+           varnames[[1]] = jstring(strings[1]),
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"        spread_values(
          varnames[[1]] ="
>           varnames[2] = jstring(strings[2]),
Error: unexpected ',' in "          varnames[2] = jstring(strings[2]),"
>           varnames[3] = jstring(strings[3])
Error in prep_path(...) : object 'strings' not found
>         ) 
Error: unexpected ')' in "        )"
```

I can't figure out what kind of object to put in front of the `=` so that the `=` is recognized.

---

Here is a toy example using MrFlick's solution:

```
> sample_json <- '[
+     {
+         "id": 10097652,
+         "members": 2386,
+         "category": {
+             "id": 23,
+             "name": "Outdoors & Adventure",
+             "shortname": "Outdoors"
+         }   
+   }
+ ]'
> 
> group_category1 <- sample_json %>%  as.tbl_json %>% 
+     gather_array %>%  #gather_keys %>% 
+     spread_values(
+       group_id = jstring("id")
+   ) %>%
+       enter_object("category") %>% 
+       spread_values(
+         category_id = jstring("id"),
+         category_name = jstring("name"),
+         category_short_name = jstring("shortname")
+       ) 
> head(group_category1)
  document.id array.index group_id category_id        category_name category_short_name
1           1           1 10097652          23 Outdoors & Adventure            Outdoors
> 
> my_spread_values <- function(x, names, values) { 
+     stopifnot(length(names) == length(values))
+     do.call("spread_values", c(list(x), setNames(as.list(values), names )))
+  } 
> varnames <-  c("category_id", "category_name", "category_shortname")
> strings <-  c("id", "name", "shortname")
> 
> group_category2 <- sample_json %>%  as.tbl_json %>% 
+   gather_array %>% 
+   spread_values(group_id = jstring("id")) %>% 
+ enter_object("category") %>% my_spread_values( 
+     varnames, list(jstring(strings[1]), jstring(strings[2]), jstring(strings[3]) ) )
> head(group_category2)
  document.id array.index group_id category_id        category_name category_shortname
1           1           1 10097652          23 Outdoors & Adventure           Outdoors
>
```

And that works PERFECTLY!  (once some careless mistakes I had made were fixed!)

Comment: Why aren't you doing the `gather_array` and first `spread_values` in the second example (ie `group_category2`)? You are not passing the same input json object to `spread_values` and `my_spread_values`.

Comment: You are absolutely correct!  Your code works perfectly.  THANK YOU!

NB: I'm correcting the question, so it has the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a variant following @MrFlick's example that I am now using:

```
my_spread_values <- function(x, names_list, string_type) {
  # A wrapper for "spread_values" that taks a list of names and a string type. Easier to read and much less code.
  do.call("spread_values",
    c(list(x), setNames(lapply(names_list, string_type), as.list(names_list) ) ) )
}
```

with a URL defined according to the documentation here: http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/docs/

```
raw_contents <- GET(url = url)
json_raw <- httr::content(raw_contents, type = "text")
json_contents <- sub('^\\{"results":\\[', "[", json_raw)
json_contents <- sub('\\],"meta"\\:\\{.*\\}.$', "]",json_contents)
my_tbl_json <- gsub('\\\\/', "/",json_contents)  %>% as.tbl_json

num_array <- c("created", "id", "lat", "lon", "members", "score")

group_numerics <- my_tbl_json %>% 
  gather_array %>% 
  my_spread_values(num_array, jnumber )  %>% 
  select(-document.id)
group_numerics$created <- as.POSIXct(group_numerics$created/1000, origin = "1970-01-01")
```

A more extended example is [this set of working code](https://github.com/smithjd/tidymeetups) that uses the tidyjson package to process data from a real API data source.

Comment: This is basically a link-only answer which isn't super helpful if the link becomes out of date. You should attempt to include the relevant parts of the answer directly in your post.

Comment: I'll add more detail.

Answer (score 2):

In general, R does not allow you to dynamically specify parameters names with R variables. You would have to build the actual call dynamically with `do.call` however this would not play well with the `%>%` piping syntax. We can create an alternative version of the function that would be more dynamic

```
my_spread_values <- function(x, names, values) {
    stopifnot(length(names)==length(values))
    do.call("spread_values", c(list(x), setNames(as.list(values), names)))
}
```

And then you can call it like

```
enter_object(object) %>% my_spread_values(
    varnames, 
    list(jstring(strings[1]),jstring(strings[2]),jstring(strings[3]))
)
```

Or if you're always expanding the strings with a simple `jstring`

```
enter_object(object) %>% my_spread_values(
    varnames, 
    lapply(strings, jstring)
)
```

Comment: That is VERY helpful!  I was close to figuring out the restriction on parameter names, but nowhere near a strategy for dealing with it.  I've studied your suggestion and experimented with it in several different permutations, all without success so far.

Your answer suggests that you understand the context of what I'm trying to do very clearly.  I'm adding a test / comparison with a toy bit of json above to show my results.

Comment: I have to say that tidyjson seems like the way to go.  Several of the other packages specialize in creating JSON, but tidyjson is the one that has a strategy that seems promising to me for obtaining good data frames from all the sources that provide data in JSON format.